# How to call one fragment from another fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've created three tabs using ActionBarSherlock and have loaded three different fragments in them.

In a usecase, I've to load a fragment in Tab C, when a list element in the fragment of Tab B is clicked. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to let the activity handle cross-fragment coordination. Your Fragment B should notify the owning activity when a list element is tapped. Then your activity can load a new fragment or tab.

Comment: By implementing a callback interface?

Comment: That's one way of doing it, although if you're never going to use the Fragment in another activity, you can just keep a reference to the Activity and call its methods directly.